# How can I get column filled with working-days (no weekend AND no vacations)?

Tags: date, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a solution which will allow me to fill a table with the exact dates of working days (excluding weekends and also excluding a set of holidays) for a given period.

In 'Sheet1'!A1 --> I enter the start-date
In 'Sheet1'!B1 --> I enter the period (e.g 10 days)
In 'Holidays'!B2:B, I have a list of dates of national holidays and vacation-days

I currently use:

```
=FILTER(ArrayFormula('Sheet1'!A1+ROW('Sheet1'!YV1:YV14)-1),WEEKDAY('Sheet1'!A1+ROW('Sheet1'!YV1:YV14)-1,2)<6)
```

Which provides me with a set of 10 weekdays starting from the date I enter, but
a) the holidays are not taken into account and 
b) also the range is set to fixed 10 days (I require flexibility in the defined period)

**How can I get 'Sheet1'!C2:C to be filled with the 10 working days where no weekend AND no holidays are displayed?**

Your help will be much appreciated!
Cheers, Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, enter your start date in C2 (say `=A1`) and in C3 and copied down:

```
   =WORKDAY.INTL(C2;1;1;Sheet2!B$2:B)
```

as adjusted for your choice of which days of the week are considered weekends.

Further details [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294972).

Comment: This works great for the workdays (weekends AND vacations are left out) in my list.

Still looking how I can limit the list-size to the given amount of days (10 lines if period=10 and 20 lines if period=20)

Thanks for your input pnuts! :)

Comment: Awesome!! BIG thumbs UP!!